# Simple slider app, quick question

Tags: objective-c

Everything looks right, and yet something is missing. Could you please take a look?

**.m**

```
@synthesize textLabel;
@synthesize slider;

- (IBAction)setLabel:(id)sender {
   int res = [slider value]; 
   NSLog(@"something changed %d", res);

[textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[slider value]]];
}
```

**.h**

```
@interface SlidaAppDelegate : NSObject {
    UILabel *textLabel;
    UISlider *slider;
    NSString *text;
}

- (IBAction)setLabel:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
```

Whenever slider moves, i see value update correctly, however simulator shows strange numbers
[image]

Simulator shows

[image]
[image]

Xib setup is as follows:

[image]

Please advise

***UPDATE <---------------------------------------- ***

Problem went away when i changed

```
[textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[slider value]]];
```

to

```
[textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",res]];
```

I don't fully understand why that it though, considering that

```
int res = [slider value];
```

**If possible, please explain**

Comment: Probably `textLabel` isn't connected assuming you meant it stays 0 in the label.

Comment: Have you set the slider max / min ?

Comment: res gets updated, it though [slider value] is always 0

Comment: @Sidyll, yes Slider 0-100, label initial at 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bet is that value returns a float which is in between 0 and 1. So when you assign it to an int, it gets rounded down to 0.

Make res a float.

EDIT

%d wants an int, you were giving it a float with [slider value]. So it must have interpreted that value in a strange way. See [DOC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)

Comment: I too was wondering how this would work, as [slider value] returns float, but this seems to be ok when assigned to int

Comment: So the NSLog outputs the correct value, but the textLabel does not?